# Should opening a bounty on a protected question be disallowed?

Tags: discussion, bounty, protected-questions

A user has opened a bounty on the following question, but the question is protected:

[How to check if type of a variable is string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4843173/200783)

Should this be disallowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why should this be disallowed? The chance that a new Stack Overflow user will write a first-class answer deserving the bounty (but is now unable to, because of the protection) is very small.

The bounty is placed to attract more attention to the question. Protecting the question will make sure the 'collateral' *unwanted* attraction does not cause any harm. I'm definitely not calling for every bountied question to be protected, but in this case I'd call it a happy coincidence.

Comment: Apologies - I thought **protected** meant that _nobody_ could add answers.

Comment: @user200783 never mind - that's when a question is *locked*. But then you can't place a bounty on it either.